# Emitting Server Sent Events about a resource update in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, server-sent-events

I am new to Server-Sent events. I am working with a Spring Boot application with a front-end in React.

Here, we have a requirement, if, at the same time, more than one user opens a resource in UI, then the app needs to notify all these users in case, one of them is updating the same resource.

In this regard, I was searching for a relevant article in order to integrate Server-Sent Event with my Spring Boot application, I found: https://betterprogramming.pub/server-sent-events-on-react-and-spring-webflux-5f532b04633.

From this, what I understood is that, I have to add web flux dependency to the existing Spring Boot application and expose an endpoint for emitting the event.

But in my app, an update of the resource is being done with end-point: `/api/resource1` and events are going to be emitted from the app with another end-point: `/api/end-point-2` as follows:

The main resource endpoint responsible for updating the object is as follows:

```
 @RestController
    public class ResourceController {
    
        @CrossOrigin(allowedHeaders = "*")
        @GetMapping(value = "/api/resource1/")
        public MyObj updateMyObj(MyObj myObj) {
           ...
           return myRepository.save(myObj);
        }
    }
```

Other end-point responsible for emitting the event is going to be as follows:

```
@RestController
public class ResourceController { //THIS IS GOING TO NOTIFY THE CLIENTS AT 1 SEC INTERVAL

    @CrossOrigin(allowedHeaders = "*")
    @GetMapping(value = "/api/end-point-2/", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<MyObj> getMyObj() {
    
        return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .map(it ->  <NOT ABLE TO UNDERSTAND WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE>);

    }
}
```

Here, I am not able to understand, how an update in first end point will get communicated to the second end point in order to notify the clients.

Could anyone please help here ? Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use a locking mechanism (optimistic, pessimistic) on the resource? So when a user clicks update u can use the request the user sends to directly answer if succeeded. The user can than try again if the resource is locked. In that way u will keep ur client-server architecture.

Comment: Yeah, @M.Dan that I thought of locking actually so that only one user at a time is able to edit the resource. But on the update of the resource, I would like to notify all users currently viewing the resource regarding the update.

Comment: Okay understood. In our project we use versioning for this. The user has to provide a verison header field which is an int. On update the server checks if the version the user provided is the current. If that is not the case the update fails and the user can request the new object. We use this header field: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-Match

Comment: @Joy Did you find the solution/way to do what you described above? I'm trying to find the same thing and having the same doubts like you had.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing quite similar problem. It seems like [FluxSink](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/FluxSink.html) might be helpful to store emitted events.

Then you could use ApplicationEventPublisher to publish saved entity or just proper info: `MyObjSavedEvent`.

On the other hand this solution needs more changes in architecture structure and it seems like really well suitable for **CQRS** and **event sourcing** approach where we store events in event store.

I am still researching possible solutions. Gonna let you know if I come across something useful.